# How to define a Helper class in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I'm trying to create a Helper class using the Lumen Framework, but it's not working.

#### Files Structure

**composer.json** *./composer.json*

```
    [...]
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Libraries\\": "app/Libraries"
        }
    },
    [...]
```

**Controller that is calling to the Helper Class** *./app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use \Libraries\Helpers;

class UserController extends Controller {

  /**
   * Show a list of all of the application's users.
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function index() {
    return Helpers::test();
  }
}
```

**Helper Class** *./app/Libraries/Helpers.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Helpers {
  public function test() {
    return "test";
  }
}
```

**Calling the UserController@index** *./routes/web.php*

```php
    [...]
    $router->get('/', 'UserController@index');
    [...]
```

**Error in route**

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

I'm trying everything but the Helper class are not working.

Comment: Additional to the given answer below... You're also trying to call a non-static method static. Instead of `public function test() {` define your method as static (`public static function test() {`) when you want to call this method as static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `App` in front of your namespace in the `UserController`.

```
use App\Libraries\Helpers;
```

Also, there is no need to add the extra autoload rule in your composer.json. `app/libraries` is already in the first rule. All subfolders are always included.